# How to apply wilcox.test for two columns in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to apply the wilcox for 2 columns, and each are from different dataframes,

Below is my code, but it returns the error "Error: R (12): Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : "

````
Week1_data <- week1$Wk1_feature_value
Week2_data <- week2$Wk2_feature_value

#Creating Vectors
Week1 <- c(Week1_data)
Week2 <- c(Week2_data)

y <- wilcox.test(Week1~Week2, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)


Hope anyone can help me.```
````

Comment: Please share some sample data. The error  indicates some problem with reading data and may not be the problem with test. run line by line and see what works and what not.

Comment: Thank you @anuanand !

I receive the error on the formula "wilcox.test(Week1~Week2, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)" variable lengths differ (found in 'Week2').

But I don't know how to solve it.

I will attached the sample data.